# LWIP Error: Unknown arguments configuration

Tags: node.js, image, node-modules

Have issue when try use lwip resize
It's function

```
function resize(path, width, height) {
 lwip.open(path, function(err, image){
    console.log(image)
    console.log(path)
    console.error(err)
   image.resize(width, height)
 })}

resize("/home/peter/webstorm/testProject/public/upload/image.png", 150, 150);
```

console log is :

Image {
  __lwip: LwipImage {},
  __locked: false,
  __trans: false,
  __metadata: null }

/home/peter/webstorm/testProject/public/upload/image.png

null

Error is :

Error: Unknown arguments configuration,150,150

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an argument, `width` and `callback` are required, so you would have to do the following:

```
image.resize(width, height, function(err,image){
  if(err){
    throw(err)
  }
})
```

[lwip#resize](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip#resize)

Answer (score 0):

When passing variables `width` or `height` to the function `resize` be sure it is typeof Number.
Probably `parseInt` can be your solution:

```
function resize(path, width, height) {
   lwip.open(path, function(err, image){
   console.log(image)
   console.log(path)
   console.error(err)
   image.resize(parseInt(width), parseInt(height), callback)
})}
```